# Creating a map with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Trying to create a heatmap of Company X employees by zip code over time in the New York area. The shapefile loads and plots correctly, and I have a data frame with the following columns: zip code, res2004, res2005, ..., res2014

**Shapefile**

Map 1 is the shapefile. Essentially, it is a smaller version of the Zip Code Tabulation Area shapefile provided by the census.

**Data**

zip_allyr is the data frame with the counts by zip code by year. The columns are:
zip_code, res2004, res2005, ..., res2014

Where res2004 is the number of residents in a given zip code in 2004.

**Code**

```
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)

map1 <- readShapeSpatial("...tristate1.shp")
plot(map1) #test that map shows

map2 <- fortify(map1, region="ZCTA5CE10") #Fortify map shapefile
ggplot() + geom_map(map=map2, data=zip_counts, aes(map_id=zip_code, fill=res2014))
```

This results in the following error:

```
Error in exists(name, env) : argument "env" is missing, with no default
```

Can someone let me know what I am missing?

**EDIT 1:** Added shapefile and data descriptions

Comment: A little more info on what `map1` and `zip_allyr` are would help - data column names, etc etc.

Comment: @Spacedman added short descriptors into the question. map1 is the shapefile, zip_counts is simply the count of residents by zip code by year, from 2004-2014. There is a column for each year from 2004-2014 in zip counts.